# sorting date/time in french with moment.js

Tags: jquery, datatables, momentjs

So my current problem with my sort is that I need to be able to sort if there are minutes included with the time and if there are not. The sort will break if minutes are not included. I haven't figured out how to get it to work with or without minutes in the date. Is it possible to turn off 'strict' parsing? Thx

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 moment.locale('fr', {
        months : "janvier_février_mars_avril_mai_juin_juillet_août_septembre_octobre_novembre_décembre".split("_"),
        monthsShort : "janv._févr._mars_avr._mai_juin_juil._août_sept._oct._nov._déc.".split("_"),
        weekdays : "dimanche_lundi_mardi_mercredi_jeudi_vendredi_samedi".split("_"),
        weekdaysShort : "dim._lun._mar._mer._jeu._ven._sam.".split("_"),
        weekdaysMin : "Di_Lu_Ma_Me_Je_Ve_Sa".split("_"),
        longDateFormat : {
            LT : "HH:mm",
            LTS : "HH:mm:ss",
            L : "DD/MM/YYYY",
            LL : "D MMMM YYYY",
            LLL : "D MMMM YYYY LT",
            LLLL : "dddd D MMMM YYYY LT"
        },calendar : {
            sameDay: "[Aujourd'hui à] LT",
            nextDay: '[Demain à] LT',
            nextWeek: 'dddd [à] LT',
            lastDay: '[Hier à] LT',
            lastWeek: 'dddd [dernier à] LT',
            sameElse: 'L'
        },
        relativeTime : {
            future : "dans %s",
            past : "il y a %s",
            s : "quelques secondes",
            m : "une minute",
            mm : "%d minutes",
            h : "une heure",
            hh : "%d heures",
            d : "un jour",
            dd : "%d jours",
            M : "un mois",
            MM : "%d mois",
            y : "une année",
            yy : "%d années"
        },
        ordinalParse : /\d{1,2}(er|ème)/,
        ordinal : function (number) {
            return number + (number === 1 ? 'er' : 'ème');
        },
        meridiemParse: /PD|MD/,
        isPM: function (input) {
            return input.charAt(0) === 'M';
        },
        // in case the meridiem units are not separated around 12, then implement
        // this function (look at locale/id.js for an example)
        // meridiemHour : function (hour, meridiem) {
        //     return /* 0-23 hour, given meridiem token and hour 1-12 */
        // },
        meridiem : function (hours, minutes, isLower) {
            return hours < 12 ? 'PD' : 'MD';
        },
        week : {
            dow : 1, // Monday is the first day of the week.
            doy : 4  // The week that contains Jan 4th is the first week of the year.
        }
    });

moment.locale('fr');


    // attaches the moment plugin for datatables

//This will work if minutes are included on all dates
   $.fn.dataTable.moment("dddd, D MMMM [à] H:mm [h]", 'fr');// dimanche, 15 juillet 11:01


$('#sort').dataTable( {
    "paging": false,
    "info": false,   

} );
```

});

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see anything in the above code that actually tries to perform a sort.  Please remove the unnecessary bits, and create a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Matt Johnson HI I have a jsfiddle example: [jsfiddle](http://ttp//jsfiddle.net/Tiki16/3vLLvscr/81/)

Comment: That's fine, but you need to put the code in your question also.  Please edit your question to include a *minimal* example of the problem.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should not be doing sorting based on the formatted output string, but rather on the underlying `Date` object which `moment` wraps or via methods that `moment` exposes that would give you a sort friendly value or perform a date comparison.  Some options include:

```
// working with underlying values
var momentObj = moment(/* some parameter value */); // instantiate object by whatever means you like
var msUnix = momentObj.valueOf(); // millisecond offset from start of Unix epoch
var unix = momentObj.unix(); // second offset from start of Unix epoch

// working with comparisons
if(momentObj.isBefore('2015-11-09')) { // do something };
if(momentObj.isSame('2015-11-09')) { // do something };
if(momentObj.isAfter('2015-11-09')) { // do something };
if(momentObj.isBetween('2015-11-09','2016-11-09')) { // do something };
```

Comment: Yes, and also note that `+moment()` gives the same as `valueOf`, so if the OP is using any type of common sort routine, they should just be able to use the raw `moment` objects as well.